# How do I write a CASE with 2 conditions and an OR statement inside the second condition?

Tags: sql, case

I am using SQL and trying to write a CASE statement with two conditions, where the second condition has an OR.

I have tried using OR for this condition but it is not working, I have also tried using the IN function but that does not seem to support '%' Wild Cards.

```
CASE
    WHEN 'Column1' LIKE '%a%' AND 'Column1' NOT LIKE '%b%' OR '%c%' THEN 
         'NewValue'
END 




CASE 
    WHEN 'Column1' LIKE '%a%' AND 'Column1' NOT IN ('%b%', '%c%') THEN 
         'NewValue'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIKE` is a binary operator.  You need to include both every time it is used.  And then you need parentheses.  However, you probably intend:

```
(CASE WHEN 'Column1' LIKE '%a%' AND
           'Column1' NOT LIKE '%b%' AND
           'Column1' NOT LIKE '%c%'
      THEN 'NewValue'
 END)
```

Comment: I meant something similar to that but the issue I am having is with the OR operator, i.e. If a column1 has a value of a in it and does not have a value of b or c in it then New Value. 

(CASE WHEN 'Column1' LIKE '%a%' AND
           'Column1' NOT LIKE '%b%' OR
           'Column1' NOT LIKE '%c%'
      THEN 'NewValue'
 END)

Comment: @MorningMan . . . The logic that you want is actually **AND** not **OR**.  You want a string that doesn't have `'b'` AND it doesn't have `'c'`.

Comment: Yes, you are 100% correct Thank You! Seems I got caught up with how my team requested as an OR and translated that to the SQL OR operator, when it should of been an AND. Thank you!